# Bootstrap 4 tabs not switching content when leading number is used in tab ID

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-4

Using bootstrap v4 tabs, content of tab is not switching when I use a leading numeral as the tab ID. The other tabs work normally. The tab with the leading numeral itself will switch to the active state, but the corresponding content won't display.

Is this a bug, or am I overlooking something?

This code is taken almost exactly from the bootstrap documentation, I've just added a leading numeral to the second tab:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#2-profile" role="tab">2-Profile</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" role="tab">Messages</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#settings" role="tab">Settings</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" role="tabpanel">... home</div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="2-profile" role="tabpanel">... profile</div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="messages" role="tabpanel">... messages</div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="settings" role="tabpanel">... settings</div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because element ID is not allowed to start with a number. It's just a HTML thing.

Source: [ID’s Cannot Start With a Number](https://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/)